# SQL: How to move columns into another table whilst also adding extra entires?

Tags: c#, sql

```
INSERT INTO Bookings (departing, arriving, departure_date, departure_time, arrival_time, price)
    SELECT depart_from, arrive_in, travel_date, departure_time, arrival_time, price
    FROM train
    WHERE (train_ID = @p_ID_choice);
```

Above is a query that takes several columns from a table called "train" and inserts them into another called "booking".

I would like to add to that query that it should also insert the string "manager" into a column called "user_type". The string "manager" does not exist in the table I am copying from, I simply wish to add it to the query.

Comment: I would make a quick suggestion @AndrewGourlay, do a google search on Sql `INSERT INTO SELECT to gain a better understanding on what it is you're trying to do based on `Dudu Markovitz` answer..

Comment: yeah thanks... I am doing some background reading now. The problem was that I didn't really know what I was looking for or how to best describe the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Bookings (user_type,departing, arriving, departure_date, departure_time, arrival_time, price)
    SELECT 'manager',depart_from, arrive_in, travel_date, departure_time, arrival_time, price
    FROM train
    WHERE (train_ID = @p_ID_choice);
```

Comment: thanks mate. Actually much easier than I thought. So is that a general rule, when you tell it what columns to fill, it will use the values you give in the exact order you give them?

Comment: Thanks. Also could I for example replace 'manager' with @manager and the modify the parameters?

Comment: If it legal in the SELECT than it is also legal in the context of the INSERT